# СопряженнОм или сопряженнЫм?

Tags: орфография

подкупе, сопряженнОм с вымогательством, или сопряженным с вымогательством?

Answer (score 5):

(Уличён **в**, попался **на**) подкуп**е** (каком?) сопряжённ**о**м... (предложный падеж)

(Промышлял) подкуп**о**м (каким?) сопряжённ**ы**м... (творительный падеж)